# XML Serilazation root element missing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

Hi I'm trying to learn some xml serialization and deserialization in C# so i wrote a program to read and put data in an xml document but when i run my code to serialize I get a System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (0, 0).' and something about root element missing, you can see my code below and hopefully someone can help

**School.cs**

```
namespace SchoolAssignment
{
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "grade")]
public class Grade
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    private School m_parent;
    public void setParent(School p_parent)
    {
        m_parent = p_parent;
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "grades")]
public class Grades
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "grade")]
    public List<Grade> Grade { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "room")]
public class Room
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    private School m_parent;
    public void setParent(School p_parent)
    {
        m_parent = p_parent;
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rooms")]
public class Rooms
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "room")]
    public List<Room> Room { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "course")]
public class Course
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    private School m_parent;
    public void setParent(School p_parent)
    {
        m_parent = p_parent;
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "courses")]
public class Courses
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "course")]
    public List<Course> Course { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "student")]
public class Student
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private School m_parent;
    public void setParent(School p_parent)
    {
        m_parent = p_parent;
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "students")]
public class Students
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "student")]
    public List<Student> Student { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "School")]
public class School
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "grades")]
    public Grades Grades { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "rooms")]
    public Rooms Rooms { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "courses")]
    public Courses Courses { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "students")]
    public Students Students { get; set; }

    private static String m_path = "";

    public static School SchoolFromXML(String path)
    {
        m_path = path;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(School));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
        School m_sys = (School)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
        m_sys.setParents();
        return m_sys;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(School));
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(m_path);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        writer.Close();
    }

    public void setParents()
    {
        foreach (Grade m_child in Grades.Grade)
            m_child.setParent(this);
        foreach (Room m_child in Rooms.Room)
            m_child.setParent(this);
        foreach (Course m_child in Courses.Course)
            m_child.setParent(this);
        foreach (Student m_child in Students.Student)
            m_child.setParent(this);
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        School school = School.SchoolFromXML("C:/Skole/xml/SchoolAssignment/SchoolAssignment/School2.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Multiple root elements? That sounds wrong...

Comment: What are the contents of the XML file?  Is there any chance it contains multiple XML fragments left over from repeated attempts to serialize to XML?

Comment: In order for us to answer your question, we're going to need a [mcve].  You've included your code so you're most of the way there, but we need to see a sample of XML that demonstrates the problem.  See: [ask].